# Error on timer activity

Tags: android, android-activity, timer, handler

i have timer on my activity which change activity with another  activity its working fine on AVD but in real device i get the error here is the code :

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
        final Intent mainIntent = new Intent(splash.this,MainActivity.class);
        splash.this.startActivity(mainIntent);
        splash.this.finish();
        }
        }, 5000);
```

and here is the logcat output :

```
01-14 21:16:39.146: E/AndroidRuntime(10899): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-14 21:16:39.146: E/AndroidRuntime(10899): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
01-14 21:16:39.146: E/AndroidRuntime(10899):    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
01-14 21:16:39.146: E/AndroidRuntime(10899):    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:596)
01-14 21:16:39.146: E/AndroidRuntime(10899):    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:444)
01-14 21:16:39.146: E/AndroidRuntime(10899):    at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:817)
01-14 21:16:39.146: E/AndroidRuntime(10899):    at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2854)
01-14 21:16:39.146: E/AndroidRuntime(10899):    at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:1521)
01-14 21:16:39.146: E/AndroidRuntime(10899):    at android.widget.ImageView.resolveUri(ImageView.java:628)
01-14 21:16:39.146: E/AndroidRuntime(10899):    at android.widget.ImageView.setImageResource(ImageView.java:361)
01-14 21:16:39.146: E/AndroidRuntime(10899):    at com.safshari.mandegar.ImageAdapter.getView(ImageAdapter.java:70)
01-14 21:16:39.146: E/AndroidRuntime(10899):    at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2597)
01-14 21:16:39.146: E/AndroidRuntime(10899):    at android.widget.GridView.makeAndAddView(GridView.java:1344)
01-14 21:16:39.146: E/AndroidRuntime(10899):    at android.widget.GridView.makeRow(GridView.java:344)
01-14 21:16:39.146: E/AndroidRuntime(10899):    at android.widget.GridView.fillDown(GridView.java:286)
01-14 21:16:39.146: E/AndroidRuntime(10899):    at android.widget.GridView.fillFromTop(GridView.java:420)
01-14 21:16:39.146: E/AndroidRuntime(10899):    at android.widget.GridView.layoutChildren(GridView.java:1232)
01-14 21:16:39.146: E/AndroidRuntime(10899):    at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2431)
01-14 21:16:39.146: E/AndroidRuntime(10899):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14482)
01-14 21:16:39.146: E/AndroidRuntime(10899):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4469)
01-14 21:16:39.146: E/AndroidRuntime(10899):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
01-14 21:16:39.146: E/AndroidRuntime(10899):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14482)
01-14 21:16:39.146: E/AndroidRuntime(10899):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4469)
01-14 21:16:39.146: E/AndroidRuntime(10899):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1669)
01-14 21:16:39.146: E/AndroidRuntime(10899):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1527)
```

and my device is Galaxy s4 if info is needed .

andhere is my image adapter code where should iput picasso code ?

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private Context mContext;

// Keep all Images in array
public Integer[] mThumbIds = {
        R.drawable.pic1,R.drawable.pic2,
        R.drawable.pic3,R.drawable.pic4,
        R.drawable.pic5,R.drawable.pic6,
        R.drawable.pic7,R.drawable.pic8,
        R.drawable.pic9,R.drawable.pic10,
        R.drawable.pic11,R.drawable.pic12,
        R.drawable.pic13,R.drawable.pic14,
        R.drawable.pic15,R.drawable.pic16,
        R.drawable.pic17,R.drawable.pic18,
        R.drawable.pic19,R.drawable.pic20,
        R.drawable.pic21,R.drawable.pic22,
        R.drawable.pic23,
        R.drawable.pic25,R.drawable.pic26,
        R.drawable.pic27,R.drawable.pic28,
        R.drawable.pic29,R.drawable.pic30,
        R.drawable.pic31,R.drawable.pic32,
        R.drawable.pic33,R.drawable.pic34,
        R.drawable.pic35,R.drawable.pic36,
        R.drawable.pic37,R.drawable.pic38,
        R.drawable.pic39,R.drawable.pic40,
        R.drawable.pic41,R.drawable.pic42,
        R.drawable.pic43,R.drawable.pic44,
        R.drawable.pic45,R.drawable.pic46,
        R.drawable.pic47,R.drawable.pic48,
        R.drawable.pic49,R.drawable.pic50,
        R.drawable.pic51,R.drawable.pic52,
        R.drawable.pic53,R.drawable.pic54,
        R.drawable.pic55


};

// Constructor
public ImageAdapter(Context c){
    mContext = c;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mThumbIds.length;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return mThumbIds[position];
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {         
    ImageView imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
    imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
    imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);
    imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(250, 250));
    return imageView;
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fastest way to resolve your problem is to use the Picasso library from Jake Wharton. It enables in one line of code to load your image and manage caching, transformations, download etc..

Here is the link to download the library: 
http://square.github.io/picasso/

All the code you need is :

```
Picasso.with(context).load("http://i.imgur.com/DvpvklR.png").into(imageView);
```

Place this in your grid adapter, provide image URL or drawable or... and replace imageView by your image holder.

It should work like a charm :)

Comment: i added the jar file and i put my image adapter in question where should i put this code into ? @aurelien_lepage

Comment: Picasso.with(mContext).load(mThumbIds[position]).fit().into(imageView);   Put this code in your getView() method. It should work.

Comment: 01-14 23:24:24.751: E/AndroidRuntime(30965): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-14 23:24:24.751: E/AndroidRuntime(30965): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.squareup.picasso.Picasso
01-14 23:24:24.751: E/AndroidRuntime(30965):  at com.safshari.mandegar.ImageAdapter.getView(ImageAdapter.java:73)

Comment: im getteing this error i edited my getview code like this : ImageView imageView = new ImageView(mContext);            Picasso.with(mContext).load(mThumbIds[position]).into(imageView);
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
        imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(250, 250));
        return imageView;

Comment: You have probably not added Picasso .jar to your Build Path. Right click on .jar in libs folder "Build Path" -> "Add to Build Path"

Comment: im already added the library its under referenced libraries now

Comment: You have to add to Build Path, not just add to libs folder. Have you done "Right click on .jar in libs folder "Build Path" -> "Add to Build Path"" ?

Answer (score 1):

It's not an error from your timer, you trying to load a big `Bitmap` into a `View`.
You can't load a bitmap, I recommend to resize with a maxDimension like that:
(in this case it's from a url: `input`)

```
BitmapFactory.Options option = new BitmapFactory.Options();
option.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input, null, option);

int scale = 1;
if (option.outHeight > maxDimension || option.outWidth > maxDimension) {
    scale = (int) Math.pow(2, (int) Math.round(Math.log(maxDimension / (double) Math.max(option.outHeight, option.outWidth)) / Math.log(0.5)));
}

BitmapFactory.Options option2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
option2.inSampleSize = scale;
myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input2, null, option2);
```

Comment: Where you trying to decode your bitmap ! If the problem persist you can try to use Picasso library
http://square.github.io/picasso/

Comment: You can also check here: http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html :)

Answer (score 0):

You run out of memory because you are loading an image that is too big. It might be set in the layout file of the second `Activity`, so you get the `Error` only when you fire the `Intent`. This is not related to the timer. Can you explain a bit more the situation and paste the remaining of the stack trace?

Comment: another activity is a grid full of images ! its odd cuz im runnig this on a smaller device and its worked .

Comment: It doesn't matter. The "bigger", or rather newer, the device, the more likely it has more memory, but also the more likely it has more pixels on the screen thus requiring more memory for each Bitmap. The code from [koni](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21121252/913286) is the right way to go here. If you set the images from the layout xml file, please mind the memory. You can find a rough estimation of memory per app with `ActivityManager.getMemoryClass()` (in mb)